# Help me Get to the Ubuntu 15.04 Partition, please

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I  had earlier installed Ubuntu 14.10, as a dual boot, on a  hard disk drive that had come pre-installed with Windows 8.1.

Later I had added a  solid-state drive and installed windows 10 insider preview along with the latest version of  Ubuntu (15.04). GRUB  was able to beautifully link both the versions of Windows as well as both the versions of Ubuntu.

After some updates of Toshiba, BIOS and Windows 8 there was a problem with GRUB as in the laptop would only boot to the Windows operating systems (8.1 & 10) and not boot to Ubuntu, both the old or the new version of  Ubuntu.

I was able to repair the GRUB with a live-USB. However, I am still unable to use Ubuntu (15.04). Whenever I try to use this latest version, I get a black screen with lots of white (& some green) text and it refuses to move into the GUI.

Here is what I have got regarding the  GRUB repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11188691/ (Details appended to my question)

Please could someone help me solve this problem, it is crucial that I am able to use the latest Ubuntu because a lot of important work is lying there.

**Thank you** so much.
 Greatly appreciate it.

Here is the message I got:

Boot successfully repaired.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11188691/

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdb (750GB) disk!

If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS.
If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

Comment: You say you "get a black screen with lots of white (& some green) text and it refuses to move into the GUI." Post that text! It almost certainly provides the clues needed to fix your problem. If necessary, take a digital photo of the screen when it stops working and post a link to that digital photo.

Comment: After a Windows update, don't forget to check that the power option "fast startup" is still turned off.  Can you boot Ubuntu directly from the EFI boot menu?( Hold f12 down at power-up to get boot choices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I got onto Ubuntu LiveUSB & rescued all my stuff & backed it up. I did a fresh install of the SSD with a dual boot of Windows 10 & Ubuntu 15.04. The old HDD still has Windows 8.1 & Ubuntu 14.04.

The new Ubuntu fixed the GRUB & now both the old & new Ubuntu (as well as Window 10 & 8.1) are accessible.

Thanks again everyone for your help.